# double read calls in python fuse leading to EINVAL

Tags: python, fuse

I am having trouble with python-fuse. Here is a standalone example of the issue: https://gist.github.com/ensonic/87e4108a7be64412d1c5a553b7e01f88

When mounting the fake-in-memory file system, I can list the contents , but I can read the files:

```
> ls -al ~/temp/mount/
total 1
-r--r--r-- 1 user group 34 Aug  3 22:44 test.txt
> cat ~/temp/mount/test.txt 
cat: /home/user/temp/mount/test.txt: Invalid argument
```

When I run the fuse fs in the forground (-d), I get this debug info:

```
LOOKUP /test.txt
getattr /test.txt
   NODEID: 2
   unique: 120, success, outsize: 144
unique: 121, opcode: OPEN (14), nodeid: 2, insize: 48, pid: 10342
open flags: 0x8000 /test.txt
   open[0] flags: 0x8000 /test.txt
   unique: 121, success, outsize: 32
unique: 122, opcode: READ (15), nodeid: 2, insize: 80, pid: 10342
read[0] 4096 bytes from 0 flags: 0x8000
   unique: 122, error: -22 (Invalid argument), outsize: 16
unique: 123, opcode: READ (15), nodeid: 2, insize: 80, pid: 10342
read[0] 4096 bytes from 0 flags: 0x8000
   unique: 123, error: -22 (Invalid argument), outsize: 16
unique: 124, opcode: FLUSH (25), nodeid: 2, insize: 64, pid: 10342
   unique: 124, error: -38 (Function not implemented), outsize: 16
unique: 125, opcode: RELEASE (18), nodeid: 2, insize: 64, pid: 0
release[0] flags: 0x8000
   unique: 125, success, outsize: 16
```

and my logfile has:

```
INFO:fakefs:open fake file /test.txt
INFO:fakefs:read from /test.txt, offs 0, size 4096, len 34
INFO:fakefs:read remainder
INFO:fakefs:read() = 34 bytes
INFO:fakefs:read from /test.txt, offs 0, size 4096, len 34
INFO:fakefs:read remainder
INFO:fakefs:read() = 34 bytes
INFO:fakefs:released(/test.txt) = 0
```

What I wonder is:
1) why is the read done twice (read[0] 4096 bytes from 0 flags: 0x8000)
2) why does it return EINVAL? I return the data - there is no single EINVAL in my code.

In the actual example I am implementing the rest of the fs functions too, this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is related to the tricky handling of encoding in python 2 (there is no python-fuse for py3).

Returning bytes(buf) in read() fixes it. The fuse code uses EINVAL also when things look wrong it received from the python side.